# If the Kesubah was read immediately following the birkas eirusin, before the kedushin took place, must the bracha be repeated?

Tags: halacha, blessing, marriage, wedding, ketubah

If, at a wedding, the *Kesubah* (marriage contract) was read immediately following the *[birkas eirusin](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/313723/jewish/Betrothal-Blessings.htm)*, before the *[kedushin](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Kiddushin#Giving_the_Ring_and_Saying_Harei_At_Mekudeshet_Li)* took place, must the bracha be repeated, because of the *hefsek* (interruption) between the bracha and the *kedushin*?

[Note: One may claim that the reading of the Kesubah is not considered a hefsek, because it is also relevant to the ceremony, although not to the kedushin per se.

I think this may be incorrect, based on the [reason for reading the kesubah](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/481777/jewish/The-Reading-and-Delivery-of-the-Ketubah.htm) is specifically in order to cause a hefsek after the bracha, so as to allow repeating the bracha of *Borei pri hagafen* again, before the sheva brachos.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This *teshuvah*](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%98%D7%95_%D7%9E%D7%97) from [R. Yaakov Epstein](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91_%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F_(%D7%A8%D7%91)) discusses the question of a *hefsek* between *birkat eirusin* and the *kiddushin* / *eirusin* itself. While he doesn't specifically talk about reading the *ketubah* as a *hefsek*, I think it is relevant to your question.

Essentially, it boils down to an argument regarding the status of this *berachah*. Rambam (and others) hold that the *berachah* is recited by the *mesader kiddushin* on behalf of the groom over the *mitzvah* of *kiddushin* that he is about to perform (*birkat hamitzvot*). Rosh (and others) hold that it is a more general *berachah* of praise (*birkat hashevach*), recited on behalf of everyone present.

His conclusion is:

> יש חשש ... בברכת
>   האירוסין לסוברים שהיא ברכת המצוות ומברך אותה המסדר עבור החתן שיצא
>   בברכתו, ואם החתן מדבר בין הברכה לקידושין יש בכך הפסק. ואמנם איננו
>   אומרים לו לברך בשנית לפני מעשה הקידושין שכן ספק ברכות להקל וישנה
>   דעת הרא"ש שהיא ברכת השבח
>
> There is room to worry with *birkat eirusin* according to those who hold that it is a *birkat hamitzvah* and the *mesader* recites it on behalf of he groom who fulfills his obligation with the *brachah* of the *mesader*. Thus, if the groom were to speak between the *berachah* and the *kiddushin* there would be a *hefsek*. **However, we would not tell him to repeat the *berachah* before performing the *kiddushin*, because of the principle that we are lenient when it comes to doubtful *berachot*, and there is the opinion of the Rosh that it is a *birkat hashevach*.**

Thus it seems that in your case as well, we would not require that the *berachah* be repeated, in deference to the view of Rosh.